# Can downloaded Android emails be backed up?

Tags: backup

Helpfully the nice chaps at TalkTalk accidentally deleted my mailbox. They are in process of trying to recover it but is not looking promising.

I have a snapshot of some of the emails downloaded to my android phone using the standard email app and was wondering if anyone knows of a way to backup or archive these so if I were to update my phone I wouldn't lose them and could still access them moving forward.

I have looked into several email backup apps but they all seem to require a connection to my mailbox which is not currently possible. Presumably the downloaded emails must be stored somewhere on my phone to access and backup. Rooting confuses me slightly but assume this may be the only option if someone could guide me through this or advise an easier way that would be great!

Many thanks in advance.
Shaun

Answer (score 1):

Well for this thing you have to go through two methods:

1) Rooting your device

2) Backup your email [Need Root].

**For Rooting Your Device:**

1) Download Framaroot app from Play Store and Install it on your device.
2) Open the app -> In Specify Execute type-> Install Super SU.
3) You will see some exploit character will appeared, click any of the exploit.
4) You will see a message popup- "Success, SuperSu and su binary is install". Reboot your device. That's all your device is rooted.

Source : http://menonjats.com/root-or-unroot-android-using-framaroot/

OR incase above method not work.

1) Search "Root Genius Software for PC", Download this software and Install it on your PC.

2) Connect your phone with PC using USB Debugging.

If you don't know how to open USB debugging below link will help you :

http://www.samsungsfour.com/tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-on-galaxy-smartphone-on-kitkat-4-4-2-or-higher.html

3) Open Root Genius Software and Press - Root.

Source : http://androidxda.com/download-root-genius

**For Email Backup :**

You can use adb for this:

```
adb backup -noapk -noshared -f gmail.ab com.google.android.gm
```

would backup all data of the GMail app to your PC, storing it in a file named gmail.ab in the current working directory. A restore of that snapshot then is as easy as running

```
 adb restore gmail.ab
```

Note that this will include all the settings of the GMail app.

If you prefer doing the same via an app on your device, take a look at Helium Backup.

Without root, it's not possible to access the corresponding folder on your device directly (which would be found below `/data/data/com.google.android.gm` and be owned by the GMail app, which forbids access for other apps/users, including the shell user).

Original Source : [Backup gmail emails offline](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75171/backup-gmail-emails-offline)

Comment: Have you solved the issue ??

Comment: @ShaunBlack, thank you comments add noise here unless you've something constructive to mention. If the answer worked for you, you can consider [accepting it](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)?

Comment: Why did you mention that backing up that email app using ADB requires root access because I don't see the role of root anywhere during backup? Please enlighten.

Comment: Just wanted to ask the same as @Firelord: `adb backup` 1) does not require root and 2) gains no advantages even if the device is rooted. Only exception is if the app-to-be-backed-up has opted out of backup (`ALLOW_BACKUP` set to `FALSE` in its Manifest) – but even then, it would need a 3rd element (e.g. the Xposed module "Backup all apps") to overrule that. Additionally, you've described backing up ***Gmail*** – while OP asked for the default ***Email*** app (which is a different one, usually `com.android.email`).

Comment: I had include root because-  Without root, it's not possible to access the corresponding folder on your device directly (which would be found below /data/data/com.google.android.gm and be owned by the GMail app, which forbids access for other apps/users, including the shell user).

Comment: You're informed but not your answer. You wrote "*Backup your email [Need Root]*" which explicitly means backing up email requires root access. *But ADB doesn't use root to backup an app*. Do you get it now? Consider editing the details in the beginning and specify that rooting is optional here. Also, use @ to notify somebody.